# Supremum conditions for equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples, supremum-and-infimum, equicontinuity

Suppose $\mathcal{E} \subset C_0([a, b], \mathbb R)$ is a family of functions.

1. Show that $g(x) = \{\sup f(x) : f \in \mathcal{E}\}$ is continuous does not imply that $\mathcal{E}$ is equicontinuous.
2. If $g(x) = \{\sup f(x) : f \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is continuous for every $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{E}$, is $\mathcal{E}$ equicontinuous?

I need a hint for these two questions. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @julien: the artificial continuity of the sup in my counterexample for question 1 kind of begs the hypothesis of question 2. I see nothing wrong with the questions the way they are.

Comment: I gave the question a more descriptive title.

Comment: @NateEldredge: When altering a title, make sure that part of the question was not in the title. Questions should be self-contained, but often they are not. I have placed the old title into the question.

Comment: @robjohn: Oops!  Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider
$$
f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\text{for }x\lt\frac12-\frac1{2n}\\
1-n\left(1-2x\right)&\text{for }\frac12-\frac1{2n}\le x\le\frac12\\
1&\text{for }x\gt\frac12\\
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: For hint 2, I guess you aim at a contradiction with the continuity of the sup of the subsequence. I confess I can't see it...

Comment: @julien: and it is well you can't :-) I tried to flesh out my approach, and hit a snag which motivated the counterexample in Hint 2.

Comment: I like your new hint 2, +1. So in this case, your sequence is nonincreasing and for any $\mathcal{F}$, we have $g_{\mathcal{F}}=\sup_\mathcal{F}f=f_{n}$ with $n=\min\{k\;;\;f_k\in \mathcal{F}\}$, so it's indeed continuous.

Comment: So are you saying that if $\sup_{\mathcal F}|f|$ is continuous for all $\mathcal F$, then $\mathcal E$ is equicontinuous?

Comment: @julien: Consider
$$
f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\text{for }x\lt\frac12-\frac1n\\
1-n\left(\frac12-x\right)&\text{for }\frac12-\frac1n\le x\le\frac12\\
1&\text{for }x\gt\frac12\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
I guess this would be a counterexample for both 1 and 2.

Comment: Yes, great. Thanks!